# Confused About - Judism - Christanity - Hebrew Bible - Old Testament - New Testament!

Tags: moses, jews, hebrew

I was watching a movie "Exodus - Gods and Kings" yesterday and I came to know about Moses. I am a Hindu by religion but I got curious about Moses and his deeds and how he brought changes to the lives of those Egyptian slaves.

I did some research on the internet but soon got clouded by all the terms I have never heard before. Hebrews & Samaritans, Hebrew Bible & Christian Bible and how they are interlinked, Connection between Israeli/Judism/Jews, Differnece between Catholic and Jews and different versions of Christian Bible - Old/New Testament.

I really want to understand how it all started but it seems like internet documents are so vast, I will get confused pretty quickly and to be honest, I have gone to some extent already!

Right now, I am looking for an unbiased explanations about all the above topics. I want to know if Modern Christanity has been affected by Moses and Hebrews/Judism and how all this get interlinked.

I know the explanations can be little lengthy but would really appreciate as this will clear out my doubts and confusions for good!

Comment: Welcome to the site, Harry.  If you haven't already done so, please take the [tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour) and see [how we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/). The questions you are asking here are important and very interesting, unfortunately because there are too many of them at once and because different Christian groups believe different things about this topic, they are not on-topic as is.

Comment: First understand, there are no unbiased explanations--of anything! It's literally impossible. Every author has a bias. That said, the best place to learn about the stories you're asking about is in their primary sources, which is the Old Testament. Specifically, the book of Exodus.

Comment: @Harry, your question is too broad. Your curiosity is great. Since your willing to put time into this project, you can find much of your answer by reading through the first 4 books of the bible (Moses is there). Read one more book and you would have read the "torah".  Short answer: Yes. Christianity is of course, directly affected by Judaism. Christ was Jewish! The bible is about the stories of his lineage. The church split into two with his resurrection and the destruction of Herod's temple. Asking how Christianity is affected by Judaism is like asking how apples are affected by trees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome. The history of "Bible religion" is spanning a long time and that makes thing confusing.

I'll try to sum it up for you.

1. God creates the world, He creates Adam & Eve, the first humans, from
   which all humans are born
2. Humans rebell in various ways and lose some knowledge about God.
3. God reveals itself again to [Abraham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham), head of a tribe. They form a
   Covenant, and Israel is born, from the tribe of Abraham.
4. The Israeli, having grown, begin to differentiate themselves into [12 different sub-tribes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israelites) : Reuben Simeon Levi **Judah** Dan Naphtali Gad Asher Issachar Zebulun Joseph **Benjamin**
5. At some point, there was an internal battle between them, and [they split](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ten_Lost_Tribes), in one side Judah + Benjamin = the Jews (Judah, Judahism) And we lost track of the other 10: The Samaritans claims to be from the Joseph tribe.
6. Israel, now rougly equal to the Jews, is waiting for a Messiah
7. Jesus rises, claiming he is the Messiah. Some Jews acknowledge him, some other don't. Jesus is called "Jesus Christ", hence the name of his followers, the Christians. For them, everything before Jesus Christ is called "the old testament" (= respectable, wise) and everything after is the "new testament"
8. The Christians have internal strifes, thus splitting: Catholics, Orthodox, Protestants..
9. Everyone highly rever Moses, since it dates before the splits

Comment: Thank you Offirmo. Considering the vastness of my question, you still tried to answer most of the queries by keeping your reply short and concise.